# How should the P matrix diagonal behave in a Kalman Filter?

Tags: statistics, kalman-filter

I am implementing a Kalman Filter and it happens to work pretty good, but I am worried about really understanding what the P matrix means and how to control it. I have two questions in this way.

First, I would like to know how the P matrix behaves, meaning that I want to know for example what is the difference in my code between obtaining Pvalues 1 or Pvalues 2 in the image. The blue and purple line represent the +- the P diag values. What matrixes/values do I have to change in my code to obtain different P curves ?

[Different P values obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMXLC.png)

Second, in my system there are up to 31 input signals that have to be filtered to get a stable value. This value is usually very stable over time but can happen that suddenly it changes its value very fast.

In this case, I would like to know how the P diagonal values should behave.

[Case I on the left. Case II on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKorf.png)

When there is a jump, the P values should increase and then decrease again (case I) or do they stay the same because they come from a stable filtered signal?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you refer to with "P values", but if you are talking about the filtered state estimate covariance, that does not depend at all on the measured values in the Kalman filter. You get the same behaviour in the state estimate covariance regardless of which measurements you obtain.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the covariance or variance if we are talking about the diagonal. I guess this values don't change with the input of the filter but I want to know how they change with the input matrixes R and Q for example, how does the variance curve vary with thos valuesor others.

Comment: You can find out the exact dependence by looking at how the covariance matrix changes in the prediction and update steps.